# Powershell regex to remove comma but not delimiter

Tags: regex, csv, powershell

I'm bringing a delimited CSV into PowerShell to remove line feeds with the code below which works but I've found I need to remove extra commas as well but not sure how to format the regex.

```
(Get-Content -Path $fullpath -Raw) -replace '(?<!\x0d)\x0a'," " | out-file $fullpath
```

My input CSV is:

```
"field1","field2","field3","fred,mary,john,brian","field5"
```

So I want to keep `","` (including the quotes), but remove any other commas on their own.

So I'd end up with:

```
"field1","field2","field3","fred mary john brian","field5"
```

Comment: Why regex? You have a valid CSV. If you really need to remove the commas Import-Csv, pick the field(s) and rewrite them.

Comment: @Calzor: On the assumption that you meant the sample to be valid CSV, I added the trailing quote to `"field3"`. Welcome to SO!

Comment: The problem is the csv is 'linked' inside excel and it inteprets the line feeds and extra commas messing it up. It's easier for me to fix the source at import which is via powershell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it.

```
(Get-Content -Path $fullpath -Raw) -replace '(?<!"),|,(?!")',' ' | out-file $fullpath
```

It will only match the comma's that are either not proceeded by a quote or not followed by it.
Which is true for all commas except those surrounded by quotes: `","`

To only remove the commas of a specific field, you could use Import-Csv with a Header.

```
$csvin = Import-Csv -Path $fullpath -Header f1,f2,f3,f4,f5
$csvin |%{$_.f4=$_.f4.replace(',',' ')}
$csvin |ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |Select-Object -Skip 1 |Set-Content -Path $fullpath
```

Comment: Your regex solution assumes a quoted field will never start or end with a comma.

Comment: Fixed the regex. Now it will also remove the last and first comma's between quotes. Even when you have fields with comma's next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can import the CSV file, remove commas from all fields, and write it as CSV again. No need for trying to write a regex that keeps the structure intact:

```
$data = Import-Csv foo.csv
$columns = $data | gm | where MemberType -eq NoteProperty | % Name
$newdata = $data | %{
  foreach ($c in $columns) {
    $_.$c = $_.$c -replace ',',' '
  }
}
$newdata | Export-Csv foo-rewritten.csv
```

Comment: ++, but it's always worth pointing out that `Export-Csv` uses _ASCII_ encoding by default(!), so it's advisable to always use the `-Encoding` parameter.